# I was devoloping a program which stores passwords in a CSV file but its heavily insecure , how can I store passwords more securely

Tags: python, powershell

I really wanted to harden my program as it is a prototype to create active directroy users however I was looking for advice as storing passcodes in a CSV file seems insecure yet my script relies on it as I have another powershell script which generates the AD users. Is there a way I can still encrypt the CSV file and add onto it and read it

```
import csv
import subprocess, sys
from password_generator import password_generator
def header():
    headerList = ['Name', 'username', 'passcode', 'Title', ]

    # open CSV file and assign header
    with open("users.csv", 'w', newline='') as file:
        dd = csv.DictWriter(file, delimiter=',',
                            fieldnames=headerList)
        dd.writeheader()


def add_user():
    infile = open("users.csv", "a")
    Name = str((input('enter your full name:')))
    username = str((input('enter your username:')))
    passcode = password_generator()
    Title = str((input('enter your job title:')))

    data1 = f"\n{username},{passcode},{Name},{Title}"
    data = data1.strip()  # strips white space
    infile.write(data + "\n")  # appends to new line
    print('record added succesfully !')
    infile.close()


def gen_user():
    p = subprocess.Popen(["powershell.exe",
                          "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\AD_Users.ps1"],
                         stdout=sys.stdout)
    p.communicate()


def main():
    print('Welcome to AD_USERS creation')
    print('********************************************************'
          ' **  \n'
          ' **  Please choose one of the options below:\n'
          ' **  [a] to add new AD user record\n'
          ' **  [h] to initialze headers\n'
          ' **  [G] to generate users \n'
          ' **  [q] to quit \n'
          ' ********************************************************\n')
    choice = input('pick:')
    while True:
        if choice == "a":
            add_user()
            break
        elif choice == "h":
            header()
            break
        elif choice == "G":
            gen_user()
            break
        elif choice == "q":
            break

        else:
            print('Invalid choice!')


main()  # calls all the code
```

Powershell script

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$ADUsers = Import-Csv C:\users.csv
foreach ($User in $ADUsers) {
    $Name = $User.Name
    $username = $User.username
    $password = $User.passcode
    $Title=$User.Title
    New-ADUser -Name $Name -SamAccountName $username -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-secureString $password -AsPlainText -Force) -Title $Title
    Enable-AdAccount -Identity $username
    }
```

Comment: PowerShell allows you to export secure strings as encrypted CliXMLs using DPAPI but this is only compatible with Windows and only works for the user who exported the CliXML and from the computer it was exported

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Can I please get more details , I am very lost as these terms are new yet I am very intrestested.

Comment: The thing is I have no clue how to show you with Python haha but you could definitely export to your Csv password column the CliXml (encrypted passwords) instead and then you are the only one that can decrypt them from that computer

Comment: In any case, since you're creating new AD Users I don't see a point on encrypting these passwords what you should do instead is `Set-ADUser ... -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true` for all of them

Comment: You don't. [The general approach of dealing with credentials is to avoid them and instead rely on other means to authenticate, such as certificates or Windows authentication.](https://github.com/dotnet/platform-compat/blob/master/docs/DE0001.md)

Comment: Simply don't save the password. When it's time reset the password and hand it over directly. Enable that the user has to change it AND monitor if he changed it. When he did not change it within your desired amount of time (1 week) disable the account.